# Best suited way to get response from URL and Stop further processing if no response returned from URL Call

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to get response from URL in JavaScript? If no response return, I wanted to stop it from further processing. What is the best suited way to handle this may be using callback/promise or async/await?

Comment: Use Ajax error callback

Comment: If we want to avoid callback hell, then what is the best replacement instead of using Ajax call?

Comment: Then you need to use `Promise`

Comment: What is the main use of Promise and Async/await in request-response? What are the pros and cons of it? Can you please provide any sample example of Promise until request is resolved I don't want to proceed ahead.

Comment: What, a "_callback hell_" ..? No, callbacks are the most intuitive native handling system of the AJAX calls, more is better ... You see, answers to this question can be very opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like callbacks you can do like this:

```
try {
    const response = await fetch('url');
    // Further processing
}
catch(e) {
    // Error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this using ES-6 Syntax

```
getSomething = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get("/api-url");
      const {data} = await res;
      if(data ){
        // do some thing
      } else {
        return false
      }
  }
```